# Nested percentage stops at 20% after 100%

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am iterating over all files in all directories under one top directory. I want to implement a per cent number for overall progress and individual progress.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
    u = filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files)
    laenge = len(list(u))
    j = 1
    for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files):
        print(str(round(j/laenge*100))+'% - Lese '+file)
        j+=1
```

I succeeded with the internal

```
u1 = os.walk(top_directory)
laenge1 = len(list(u1))
s1 = 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
    p1 = str(round(s1/laenge1*100))
    s1+=1            
    u = filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files)
    laenge = len(list(u))
    j = 1
    for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files):
        print(p1+'% - '+str(round(j/laenge*100))+'% - Lese '+file)
        j+=1
```

Yet `p1` ends at 20%.

I did an unelegant

```
laenge1 = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
    for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files):
        laenge1+=1
s1 = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
    u = filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files)
    laenge = len(list(u))
    j = 0
    for file in filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files):
        p1 = str(round(s1/laenge1*100))
        s1+=1 
        print(p1+'% - '+str(round(j/laenge*100))+'% - Lese '+file)
        j+=1
```

It works, but what is more elegant?

Comment: if `u` is already the filtered list (`filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.pdf'), files)`) why do you filter again in the for loop? Just use `for file in u`

Comment: For some reason then the loop is being skipped - try it yourself. EDIT: I remember why. `u` refers to a generator and a generator can only be used once. Which it is in `len(list(u))`.

Comment: Well you are resetting j inside the first loop and using it as a global counter. Everytime you change a directory in the first loop your counter will be reset.

Comment: Which is fine, the second goes from about 0 to 100% each time, the first only from about 0 to 20%.

Comment: You have to update the percents at the end. As for the 20%, I assume that there are 5 folders in your `top_directory`, out of which only the 1st contains _.pdf_ files. Add some additional prints in your code.